# Changing the password for an FTP account on vsftpd on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: macos, ftp, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi 3 as a server for local IP cameras which use plain old FTP.  I followed the instructions here at 
[Botter workshop](http://workshop.botter.ventures/2013/08/27/how-to-setup-an-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-raspberry-pi/).

While the built-in SFTP works fine, I can't seem to access the Pi via from my Mac (Fetch application). I have a feeling that I'm not using the right FTP password.

- How do I set  or reset the vsftpd server FTP account passwords running on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Also, when I try FTP localhost in the Pi terminal, I get ftp "command not found"  but I think ‘ftp’ is different (a client, vs. a server) from ‘vsftpd’ ?

**Below is a copy of what I get after a vsftpd restart**

```
pi@RPi:~ $ sudo service vsftpd status  
‚óè vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server  
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled)  
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-05-23 17:52:33 PDT; 6min ago  
Process: 1169 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)  
Process: 1165 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
Main PID: 1169 (code=exited, status=2)  
May 23 17:52:33 RPi systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.  
May 23 17:52:33 RPi systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status...MENT  
May 23 17:52:33 RPi systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.  
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

**NOTE**: moved here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425026

Comment: Check out your vsftpd configuration using this guide: http://www.techrapid.co.uk/raspberry-pi/setup-ftp-server-raspberry-pi-vsftpd/

Comment: Read up here too and see if this helps any: http://www.brennan.id.au/14-FTP_Server.html. I think you want to confirm that your version of vsftpd supports plain old insecure FTP on standard TCP port 21 for what you're working with to start. Ensure it's configurable to use FTP on TCP port 21 with no SSL/TLS encryption since that's what is required from the IP camera's. It's a shame the IP cameras wouldn't just work with the confirmed accessible SFTP using the assumed SSH FTP on TCP port 22 protocol though; something else to confirm as well perhaps.

Comment: Also, you might check up on active versus passive mode TCP port configurations on the vsftpd side as well to confirm all there is set as expected. Then from the client side (e.g. the IP cameras) you can confirm you have it set to connect correctly or ensure you can access the correlated ports from there (client to server direction). Perhaps TCP ports 20, 21, and some other range as well depending on how you configure it. Just some quick ideas to give you for potential key topics to search for in your troubleshooting and research process. Read [Active Pass](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)